# How do I echo name, price and id from a form just submitted?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have an issue with **MySQLi and PHP**.

I created a form, and once I type the desired values in and hit submit, the values are right away sent to the database. Nothing wrong with this.

What I want to happen is that: after hitting the submit button, PHP shall echo the result of the just-submitted entry. That is to say:

```
   `INSERT INTO table VALUES (x, x, y) -> SELECT x, x, y FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`
```

I have tried many methods to do this, but all of them either echo the previous entry (the one before the one just submitted) or plainly don't work.

I have tried mysqli_insert_id($conn) but this returns nothing.

*This is where my code rests at at the moment:*

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $BD);
    if (!$conn) {
        die ('<span style="color: #FF0000;">"connection failed: "</span>' .  mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $preco = $_POST['preco'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO produtos(nome, preco) VALUES ('$nome', '$preco')";
    $result = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    var_dump ($result);

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
        echo '<br>'."Succeeded!";
    } else {
        echo '<br>'."ERROR!" .'<br>'. $query ."<br>". mysqli_error($conn) .'<br><br>'. '<span style="color: #FF0000;">You have to fill all the fields.</span>';
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

to note, if of any help, var_dump outputs int(0) at the moment. 
Thanks in advance. I've been struggling like mad with this.

Comment: You can't get `mysqli_insert_id` without executing the query!!

Comment: @Saty ok, fixed it! Now the mysqli_insert_id functioning. However, it's still returning the id from the entry before the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see that you haven't even executed your query. On a side note, you should be aware of SQL injections and follow the below pattern:

```
$nome  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']);
$preco = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['preco']);

$sql    = "INSERT INTO produtos (nome, preco) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$preco."')";
$query  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$result = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

echo $result; // Check your result.
```

Comment: This works. However, the values are being uploaded duplicated to the database, and the one previous to the one of highest ID is being returned. How do I fix this?

Comment: @PauloSoares please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a support forum. Try to solve your problems yourself. In case you stuck, ask a *question*, not just reveal your problem that someone else would have to solve for you.

Comment: @YourCommonSense got it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get `mysqli_insert_id` without `executing` the query. Better use `prepare statement` to prevent from sql injection

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO produtos(nome, preco) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $nome, $preco);
    $stmt->execute();// execute query
    $conn->insert_id;// get last insert id
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO produtos(nome, preco) VALUES ('$nome', '$preco')";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$result = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
var_dump ($result);`
```

Comment: This contains the SQL injection vulnerability from the original post - not safe to use!